# Angularjs не воспринимает кирилицу

Tags: angularjs

Сама страница

```
<head>
    <script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

    <script src="workspace/usropr/usrOprApp.js"></script>
    <script src="workspace/usropr/user_operation_service/service.js"></script>
    <script src="workspace/usropr/user_operation_controller/selectController.js"></script> 
</head>
<body ng-app="usrOprApp">
    <a href="#/edit">Edit</a>
    <a href="#/list">List</a>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

usrOprApp.js

```
var usrOprApp = angular.module("usrOprApp", ["ngRoute"]);

usrOprApp.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/list", {
        templateUrl: "workspace/usropr/user_operation_template/list_operation.html",
        controller: "Controller1"
    });
    $routeProvider.when("/edit", {
        templateUrl: "workspace/usropr/user_operation_template/edit_operation.html",
        controller: "Controller2"
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        templateUrl: "workspace/usropr/user_operation_template/select.html",
        controller: "selectController"
    });
}]);

usrOprApp.controller("Controller1", ["$scope", function($scope) {

}]);

usrOprApp.controller("Controller2", ["$scope", function($scope) {

}]);
```

service.js

```
usrOprApp.factory("service", ["$http", "$rootScope", function($http, $rootScope){
    var service = {};

    var list = [];

    function getAll() {
        var conf = {
                "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                "Accept": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                "Accept-Charset": "UTF-8"
        };
        $http.get("/host/getAll", conf)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            list = data.ответ;
            $rootScope.$broadcast("list:updated");
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        });
    };
    getAll();

    service.getList = function() {
        return list;
    };

    return service;
}]);
```

selectController.js

```
usrOprApp.controller("selectController", [ "$scope", "$rootScope", "service",
        function($scope, $rootScope, service) {
            $scope.list = service.getList();
            $rootScope.$on("list:updated", function() {
                $scope.list = service.getList();
            });
        } ]);
```

а теперь шаблон select.html

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Выбор</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body" id="scrollOpertion">
                <div ng-repeat="item in list">
                <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-block">{{item.название}}</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ответ, который приходит от сервера

```
[   {
        id: 1,
        "название": "Java"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        "название": "Python"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        "название": "C++"
    }]
```

Вот когда происходит вывод на select.html через ng-repeat всё валится с ошибкой:

```
angular.js:13920Error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20next%20char…4-4%20%5B%D0%BD%5D&p2=item.%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5
```

Если выводить, только одни id, то соответственно ничего не падает и всё выводится, даже если просто прописать {{ item }} он выведет весь результат в нормальной форме. Все файлы в UTF-8, ответ приходит тоже в читаемой форме. 
Кто-нибудь встречался с таким или есть может какой способ это побороть?

Comment: json ответ от сервера очень подозрительный, т.к. `"название"` взято в кавычки, а `id` нет,  попробуйте сделать название без кавычек и проверьте на валидность свой json. И почему тег `<meta charset="utf-8">` находится в select.html а не в главной странице в теге head?

Comment: <meta charset="utf-8"> попробовал вдруг поможет. На главной странице у меня всё выставлено в head. Это просто пример результата с сервера, кавычки везде ставятся, в id я забыл поставить

Comment: Название полей в json не должно быть на кириллице, на это и ругается, у меня та же ошибка возникает, измените `название` на латиницу, например на `name`

Comment: Так вот только это и остаётся